# How to iBooks like search UI on table

Tags: iphone, search, uisearchbar

I want to show the search bar of tableview like that in iBooks. How can i reduce the width of searchbar and how it can be shown without any background color.

Also how can i hide the search box initially when the page is displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two options:

**Create your own by subclassing UITextfield**

- set border style to UITextBorderStyleNone
- set the leftView to a magnifying glass image
- set the background to a transparent png with only the round border showing
- make use if the uiimages stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight method so the background image will looks nice when stretched

**Mess around with UISearchbar, not recommended**

You can access the subviews of a UISearchbar in this way:

```
for (UIView *aSubview in [searchbar subviews]) {
            // this will remove the toolbar around the searchbar in iOS 4
    if ([aSubview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) 
    {
        [aSubview removeFromSuperview];
    }       

    // get a grip on the underlying textfield...
    if ([aSubview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")]) 
    {
        UITextField *aTextfield = (UITextField *)aSubview;

        // this won't do anything at it is already none, just experimenting
        aTextfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

        // this will remove the whole border as it is a custom background
        aTextfield.background = nil;

        // this will remove the magnifying glass
        aTextfield.leftView = nil;

        // play around even more :)
    }       
}
```

You can hide the searchbar by

- setting the hidden property to YES
- set the frame or center property to somewhere outside the visible area
- set alpha property to 0.0
- adding the searchbar to your view only when needed

Comment: Thanks Nick. It helped me a lot. 

I didn't want to hide the search bar directly. Instead it should be on top of the table view and its shown only when the table is scrolled down.

Comment: I think you can achieve that effect by putting the searchbar in the tableview scrollviews' content area and then use contentInset to hide it initially.