# How can I parse the JSON string output from HTTP POST in iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I send some parameters using POST method to my server and from there i got my response and i store it in a string "serverResponse"  .This is my server response that i stored in string

```
{ 
    "carIdentifier":[
        {"carId":"91"},
        {"carId":"93"},
        {"carId":"114"},
        {"carId":"117"}
    ]
}
```

I have separate json parsing code,but i dont know how can i give this as an input to my json parsing codes.
Following are my json parsing code

```
-(void)getcarList:(NSString *)serverResponse
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSObject *recommendedcarJSON = nil;
        NSData *recommendedcarsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverResponse]];
        NSLog(@"%@",recommendedcarsData);
        if(recommendedcarsData)
            recommendedcarJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:recommendedBooksData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

        if(!recommendedcarsData){
            NSLog(@"Error with JSON Serialization");
        } else{
            [self saveRecommendedcarData:(NSDictionary *)recommendedcarJSON];
        }
    } );
}
```

In  saveRecommendedcarData method i am creating one plist and saving this parsed data.  How can i give my server response string as an input to json parsing ??

Comment: @Bhargavi  can you tell me the answer?

Comment: The json you showed is your serverResponse string right?

Comment: yes .This is the code i used to take response from server                NSString * serverOutput= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",serverOutput]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[serverResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                               options:0
                                                 error:&jsonError];

if(jsonError!=nil)
    NSLog(@"Json_Err: %@",jsonError);

NSArray *carIdentifier = [(NSDictionary*)allValues objectForKey:@"carIdentifier"];
NSLog(@"%@",carIdentifier);

for(NSDictionary *dict in carIdentifier)
        NSLog(@"carId: %@",[dict valueForKey:@"carId"]);
```

Try this.

**UPDATE**

```
-(void)getcarList:(NSString *)serverResponse
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[serverResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&jsonError];

        if(jsonError!=nil)
            NSLog(@"Json_Err: %@",jsonError);

        NSArray *carIdentifier = [(NSDictionary*)allValues objectForKey:@"carIdentifier"];
        NSLog(@"%@",carIdentifier);

        for(NSDictionary *dict in carIdentifier)
                NSLog(@"carId: %@",[dict valueForKey:@"carId"]);

        } );
}
```

Comment: Are you using serverResponse directly or using your recommendedcarsData object ? See updated answer try to use this way ..

Comment: In data sending part (using post) there is a condition for checking whether ther serverresponse is null or not .  If(serverResponse!=NULL) {  // I added your code here }

Comment: YUP ..BHARGAVI..U R A LIFE SAVER ..Working

Comment: :u know how to add a text field or uisearch bar to UICollectioview controller header like in this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902035/how-to-ibooks-like-search-ui-on-tablehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902035/how-to-ibooks-like-search-ui-on-table

Answer (score 0):

If your want to get Value from your date Then Use Following code:

```
for(i=0 ; i < myDic.count; i++)
{
  NSLog(@"%@",[[myDic objectForKey:@"carIdentifier"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"carId"])
}
```